# How can I add a <select> option using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying js:

```
$('a[data-select="more-options"]').click(
  function () {
    $('select')
      .append($("<option></option>")
      .attr("one more additional and long option",3)
      .text("3333333333"));
  }
);
```

on HTML of

```
<span id="dropdown">A 
  <select>
    <option>this is option 1</option>
    <option>This is option 2</option>
  </select> list<br>
</span>

&nbsp;<a data-select="more-options" href="#">Add long option to the select</a>
```

but I get no results (or error).

Comment: "one more additional and long option" is it attribute ?

Comment: I do get an error when I execute the code in Chrome 35: Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'one more additional and long option' is not a valid attribute name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qm8ss/).

```
$('select').append( "<option>This is option 3</option>" );
```

This appends the third option to **select**. You can add other attributes to the option.

Answer (score -1):

Check this,

```
$('a[data-select="more-options"]').click(function () {
     $('select').append("<option>3333333333</option>");
});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/QqcZe/)**